# Filtar un array de string por letras en comun de cada elemento en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
const meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio'];
```

Quiero filtarlo de manera que cuando escriba **ae**, me permita traer un nuevo arreglo asi: `['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo']` de esa manera, her probado usando el filter, tambien el includes, o contains, pero no doy como hacerlo

Comment: Pero... porque cuando escribas `ae` te debe traer ese resultado? cual es el criterio?

Comment: Va el criterio es cualquier letra, pues que me inicie a filtrar por ella, por ejemplo: **l** y todo lo que tenga **l**

Comment: En conclusion si esa palabra tiene una **a** treae el elemnto, si tine las dos **ae** igualmente

Comment: eso es correcto const en JS?

Answer (score 0):

Debes filtrar cada palabra segun las letras, así:

```js
const consulta = "ae";
const meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio'];

const letras = consulta.split(""); //divides las letras individualmente
const filtrado = meses.filter(mes => { //filtras los meses
  for(letra of letras){ //recorres las letras
    if(mes.indexOf(letra) !== -1) //Chequeas si la letra está dentro de la palabra
      return true;
  } 
  return false;
});
console.log(filtrado)
```